# Override checkout_cart_index.xml (Magento_Checkout) for deactivating shipping-rates-validation-rules.js and shipping-rates-validator.js

Tags: shipping, magento-2.2.5

What would be the best way to override checkout_cart_index.xml in order to deactivate only these two javascript files? Thanks for your collaborations

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_item_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.messages">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\ValidationMessages" name="checkout.cart.validationmessages"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart" template="Magento_Checkout::cart.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <container name="checkout.cart.items" as="with-items">
                    <container name="checkout.cart.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="cart-container" before="-">
                        <container name="checkout.cart.form.before" as="form_before" label="Shopping Cart Items Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rewards"/>
                        <container name="cart.summary" label="Cart Summary Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="cart-summary" after="-">
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.cart.summary.title" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::text.phtml">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">Summary</argument>
                                    <argument name="tag" xsi:type="string">strong</argument>
                                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">summary title</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </block>
                            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/shipping.phtml" after="checkout.cart.summary.title">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="types" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="form.input" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                    <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="summary-block-config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shipping-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!--Step configuration components-->
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">summary-block-config</item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="block-rates" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/shipping-rates</item>
                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="block-shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/shipping-estimation</item>
                                                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                        <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">block-summary.block-shipping.address-fieldsets</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="address-fieldsets" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">address-fieldsets</item>
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">115</item>
                                                                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.city</item>
                                                                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">110</item>
                                                                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.country_id</item>
                                                                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region</item>
                                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">112</item>
                                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                                                                            <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <!-- Value of region_id field is filtered by the value of county_id attribute -->
                                                                        <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id]]></item>
                                                                            <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <!-- The following items override configuration of corresponding address attributes -->
                                                                    <item name="region" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <!-- Make region attribute invisible on frontend. Corresponding input element is created by region_id field -->
                                                                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">111</item>
                                                                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.postcode</item>
                                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">114</item>
                                                                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="checkoutProvider" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </block>
                            <container name="checkout.cart.totals.container" as="totals" label="Shopping Cart Totals">
                                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/totals.phtml">
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals</item>
                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">totals</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!-- sort order for this totals is configured on admin panel-->
                                                        <!-- Stores->Configuration->SALES->Sales->General->Checkout Totals Sort Order -->
                                                        <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/subtotal</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/subtotal</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals/shipping</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/shipping</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total</item>
                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </block>
                            </container>
                            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/coupon.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.methods.bottom" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/methods.phtml">
                                <container name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" label="Payment Methods After Checkout Button">
                                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Magento_Checkout::onepage/link.phtml" />
                                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\QuoteShortcutButtons" name="checkout.cart.shortcut.buttons" />
                                </container>
                            </block>
                        </container>
                        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Grid" name="checkout.cart.form" as="cart-items" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/form.phtml" after="cart.summary">
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="checkout.cart.order.actions"/>
                        </block>
                        <container name="checkout.cart.widget" as="checkout_cart_widget" label="Shopping Cart Items After"/>
                    </container>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" after="-">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="crosssell.product.addto" as="addto">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                                   name="crosssell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <container name="checkout.cart.noitems" as="no-items">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.empty" before="-" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/noItems.phtml">
                        <container name="checkout.cart.empty.widget" as="checkout_cart_empty_widget" label="Empty Shopping Cart Content Before"/>
                    </block>
                </container>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Additional\Info" name="additional.product.info" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/additional/info.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```